# Trying To Return The Results From This Query?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

So I am using this class called Database and using a method (select)

to get all the results from the query given

I am trying to echo or print out the results?

//database.php

```
class Database{
    public function select($table, $rows = '*', $where = null, $order = null){
    $q = 'SELECT '.$rows.' FROM '.$table;
    if($where != null)
        $q .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    if($order != null)
        $q .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
    if($this->tableExists($table))
    {
        $query = @mysql_query($q);
        if($query)
        {
            $this->numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++)
            {
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $key = array_keys($r);
                for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++)
                {
                    // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                    if(!is_int($key[$x]))
                    {
                        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1)
                            $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                        else if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1)
                            $this->result = null; 
                        else
                            $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]]; 
                    }//end if
                }//end for
            }//end for            
            return true; 
        }//endif
        else
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    else
    return false; 
} 
}
```

And this is where I am trying to output the results but idk what to do to echo/print the results out.

//select.php

```
include(includes/database.php);
$db = new Database();


$table = 'user';
$rows;
$match = $db->select($table,$rows);
var_dump($db->match);
```

I was told I wouldn't have to touch any code inside the Database class.

Comment: probably `var_dump($db->result)` will be a clue.

Comment: Such a waste using a class with `mysql_ugh*` functions.

Comment: I am getting back NULL with the var_dump.  @Fred-ii- i understand your hate. I was just brought in mid-project & trying to figure this out.

Comment: You suppose to include the class first, then instantiate it. Reverse the order of the `$db = new Database(); include(includes/database.php);`

Comment: @i-- Thanks for catching that, but I am still getting NULL from var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc mentioned probably the value should be in $db->match.

A condition can be used to check if the table returned value using $match.

```
$match = $db->select($table,$rows);

if((isset($db->match) && !empty($db->match))) {
       //iterate $db->match
       var_dump($db->match);
    } else {
       //for debugging purpose
       echo 'no values found';
    }
```

In other case the query may return no records, you can run the same query in phpMyAdmin to crosscheck the same.

Comment: Hmmm.....I get no values found when I use your script but I echo & run the same query ($q) in phpma and get the proper results. I also get Fatal error: Cannot access private property Database::$result

Comment: sorry... it should be $db->match instead of $db->result [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) Either way is to modify the database.php or to use [mysqli](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to connect to db and get values